# For every real number, a, there's another real number, b, when squared equals a

Tags: solution-verification

I'm tasked with figuring out if the following statement is correct.

$$
\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \exists s \in \mathbb{R},s^2 =r
$$

Right now my understanding is that the set of real numbers includes negative numbers.

1. Assume r is a negative real number $-1$

$$r=-1$$
$$s^2 = -1$$

2. Take the root of both sides

$$s = \sqrt{-1} = i$$

3. Since s can be $i$, an imaginary number for some real number $r$ the statement is false

$$ i \notin \mathbb{R} \rightarrow s \notin \mathbb{R} $$

And thus by contradiction it's false. My question is whether or not this proof is valid and rigorous enough. Is it safe to assume that there's no other value that s can take on that might make the statement true?

Comment: You need to prove that $s^2=-1$ has no solutions over the reals,

Comment: You want rather to prove that, for every $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $b^2\ge0$.